# How to tell that any object in a observable satisfies a condition?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have looked and it seems like there is an "All" operation that will tell if all items satisfy a condition but no "Any" is this just an oversight or am I missing something? I could recreate it with other operations, but I could say the same thing with All.

```
Observable.just(1,5,10)
          .filter(i -> i < 7)
          .reduce((c,n) -> c && n) // or "||" for any
          .subscribe(b -> /* do stuff */);
```

Am I missing something or is there really just no Any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was named `exists` in 1.x (and is again `any` in 2.x).

Comment: Gar! I'm an idiot. I got distracted by contains and didn't even notice exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `filter` operator.

Comment: Lol my bad. I was messing with C# Linq today :)